# SQL Server Analysis Services - Do I have it?

Tags: sql-server, ssas

Hi I have access to SQL Server at work and I've heard some interesting things that can be done with SQL Server Analysis Services. How do I know whether analysis services is running? Is it installed by default on the server? Would it be installed locally on my machine? Forgive what probably seems like a pretty dumb question, but I couldn't find any concrete details on Microsoft's website. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

SQL Server Analysis Services is included if you are using the following Editions:

- Standard
- Developer
- Enterprise

### Is there a way for me to know whether this component was installed?

---

It will be listed as a service - Control Panel > Admin Tools > Services, or just type "services.msc" from Start > Run.

Resources:

- [Administering Analysis Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175679%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

  - [Deploying Analysis Services Development and Production Systems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176136%28SQL.90%29.aspx)
- [Analysis Services How-to Topics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174575%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! So if I'm reading things right it sounds like Analysis Services would be installed locally on my machine and this component just wasn't included when SQL Server was installed on my computer? Nothing is actually run on the server itself?

Comment: It is run on the server itself. It's not just a matter of having the right edition, it has to be selected during installation.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I read the additional links that were provided and it sounds like it indeed needs to have been selected and installed on the server. In my case there really isn't an IT person I can go to that knows the particulars of the installation. Is there a way for me to know whether this component was installed? Thanks for your help folks!

Answer (score 6):

- Look for `MSSQLServerOLAPService` or `MSOLAP$some_name` in services

OR

- Start `SQL Server Configuration Manager` and look under `SQL Server Services`

Answer (score 1):

When you're in SQL Server Management Studio, click on the Connect button in the Object Explorer.  If you see "Analysis Services..." in the list, then you have Analysis Services.

Also, when you launch Management Studio and get the Connect to Server dialog, look in the "Server type" dropdown list.  If "Analysis Services" is listed there, then you have it.