# How to add an analysis server into SQL server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, data-warehouse, olap

I am very new to data warehouse. I just installed Sql server 2008 R2 developer edition, but when I accessed it, there was no analysis server which is for data warehouse. I also downloaded the Adventure Works DW 2008 database sample, but I did not know where to attach it.

Does anyone know about it?
thank in advance.

Comment: Did you check the box during the installation?  Check to see if it's installed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994004/sql-server-analysis-services-do-i-have-it

Comment: I checked everything. Also, following to your link, it seems to be installed already. However I cannot see any analysis server except the sql server for relational database. in the Sql configuration manager, I can see Sql Server analysis Services is running.

Comment: When connecting to an instance with SSMS, did you try selecting Analysis Services from the drop-down?

Comment: I dont see any analysis Services option from the drop-down. that's a problem

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me like you did not install the full management toolset. By default, the SQL installer only loads the basic tools. The management tool for Analysis Server is included in the complete toolset. Use the following steps to verify and/or install the complete toolset.

1. Navigate to the Control Panel
2. Click **Programs and Features**
3. Locate **Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2**
4. Click **Uninstall/Change**
5. In the *Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2* window, click **Add**
6. Step through the SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup Wizard
7. On the *Installation Type* page, ensure **New installation or add shared features** is selected.
8. Continue through the wizard
9. On the *Setup Role* page, ensure **SQL Server Feature Installation** is selected
10. On the *Feature Selection* page, make sure the following *Shared Features* are checked

    - Management Tools - Basic
    - Management Tools - Complete
11. Finish the installation wizard

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and I confirmed all @Brandon steps without success, until I see that I don't had any analysis instance. So I selected (in Feature Selection) in Instance Features\Analysis Services and finish the installation - it works now!