# SSAS development failed

Tags: ssas

When I deployed my ssas solution, the error message showed below:

The project could not be deployed to the 'localhost' server because of the following connectivity problems :

- A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running
- To verify or update the name of the target server, right-click on the project in Solution Explorer, select Project Properties, click on the Deployment tab, and then enter the name of the server.

I followed the instruction to manually setup my server name, but still didn't work

Also,I tried to use Analysis services database to connect my existing database, another warning message showed up:

- a connection cannot be made to redirector, ensure that 'SQL browser' service is running

Then I restart my browser service, still no luck.

Please help me out, thanks.

Comment: Did you install SSAS? Use this to check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994004/sql-server-analysis-services-do-i-have-it

Comment: Thank you! Turns out I didn't install analysis service component on SQL server. Things are working perfectly now :)